How to Restrict Azure Speech SDK AudioConfig to Only System Audio and Exclude Microphone Input?
Question:
I am working on a Blazor project where I integrate Azure Speech Service to perform speech-to-text transcription on system audio during screen sharing. However, I am facing an issue where audio from the microphone is still being captured, even though I've explicitly disabled it in the JavaScript code that manages the screen sharing.
Here's the flow of my implementation:
JavaScript Code (Screen Sharing)
This function enables screen sharing with system audio, while explicitly disabling the microphone tracks:


window.startScreenSharing = async function () {
    try {
        const container = document.getElementById('sharedScreen');
        if (!container) {
            console.error('Element with ID "sharedScreen" not found');
            return false;
        }

        // Start screen sharing with video and system audio
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true  // Request system audio along with video
        });

        // Disable microphone tracks
        stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.enabled = false);

        // Display the shared screen in a video element
        const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
        videoElement.srcObject = stream;
        videoElement.autoplay = true;
        videoElement.muted = true;  // Mute local audio to avoid feedback
        videoElement.controls = false;
        videoElement.style.width = '100%';
        videoElement.style.height = '100%';
        container.innerHTML = '';
        container.appendChild(videoElement);
        window.currentScreenStream = stream;

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Screen capture error:', err);
        alert('Screen capture failed. Check your browser settings.');
        return false;
    }
};



Blazor Page (C# Method to Start Screen Sharing)
The StartScreenSharing method in Blazor calls the above JavaScript function and initiates transcription:
  private async Task StartScreenSharing()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting screen sharing...");
            bool started = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("startScreenSharing");
            if (started)
            {
                isScreenSharing = true;
                StateHasChanged();
                StartTimer();

                _speechService = new SpeechToTextService(); 
                await _speechService.StartRecognitionAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to start screen sharing.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error starting screen sharing: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

Azure Speech SDK (C# Code)
This is the code where I configure the Azure Speech SDK for transcription:
 public async Task StartRecognitionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);

        // Using default speaker output
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultSpeakerOutput();
        recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

        recognizer.Recognizing += async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result.Text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Recognized: {e.Result.Text}");
            }
        };

        await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        cancellationToken.Register(async () =>
        {
            await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    }

The Problem
Despite disabling the microphone in JavaScript (stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.enabled = false)), Azure Speech SDK still captures microphone audio. Even when I explicitly block microphone access in the browser settings, Azure Speech continues to detect microphone input.
I suspect the issue lies in:
using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultSpeakerOutput();

It seems like AudioConfig ignores the JavaScript constraints and pulls audio from all available sources, including the microphone. This behavior breaks the expected functionality, as my use case only requires system audio from the shared screen.
What I Have Tried
Disabled microphone tracks in the JavaScript function managing screen sharing.
Blocked microphone access in the browser settings.
Experimented with AudioConfig options, such as FromStreamInput and FromDefaultSpeakerOutput.
None of these approaches have successfully restricted AudioConfig to system audio only.
My Questions
How can I configure Azure Speech SDK's AudioConfig to exclusively capture system audio and completely ignore microphone input?
Is there a better way to handle audio streams (e.g., passing audio streams from JavaScript to Blazor and then to Azure)?
Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Audio input can be from a microphone, file, or input stream. Audio output can be to a speaker, audio file output in WAV format, or output stream.

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

During screen sharing, the system allows System Audio, which includes microphone input. If a video is playing on the system and someone speaks simultaneously, both audio sources are combined in the results. This is a general behavior where audio from the speaker is also picked up by the microphone, leading to overlapping input.
To address this issue, you can explicitly disable acoustic echo cancellation in the audio processing pipeline when using the Azure Speech SDK. This can be done using the AudioProcessingConstants.AUDIO_INPUT_PROCESSING_DISABLE_ECHO_CANCELLATION property:
 using (var audioProcessingOptions = AudioProcessingOptions.Create(AudioProcessingConstants.AUDIO_INPUT_PROCESSING_ENABLE_DEFAULT |                                                                            AudioProcessingConstants.AUDIO_INPUT_PROCESSING_DISABLE_ECHO_CANCELLATION,                                                                           PresetMicrophoneArrayGeometry.Mono))

This  completely blocks the microphone and relies on WAV files for speech-to-text conversion.

Refer this Msdoc for Speech SDK audio input stream concepts.

One way is to separate system audio from microphone input, you can use a dedicated microphone to track voice without interference from other audio sources:
string deviceName = "Microphone (Realtek Audio)";  
using (var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromMicrophoneInput(deviceName))
{
    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourRegion");
    var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    var result = await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
}


Another Way  is to enable speaker diarization, which distinguishes between different speakers in a conversation. This allows the transcription to associate text with specific speaker IDs:

Refer this Msdoc for Real-time diarization .

conversationTranscriber.Transcribed += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech && e.Result.SpeakerId == "Guest-1/speaker ID")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Guest-1/speaker ID: {e.Result.Text}");
    }
    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be transcribed.");
    }
};


